# SearchDisplayController to detailedViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a problem. I have set up a table view with search bar.
I want when a cell is clicked to present a detailed view controller.
So far I have done that but when I search an item from the array and press it, it always displays the same detailed view controller (the view controller for indexPath.row == 0)

EDIT with the whole tableviewcontroller:

```
class CandyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

var person = [Candy]()
//add a filter
var filteredCandies = [Candy]()

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 120, green: 113, blue: 165, alpha: 100)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            // Sample Data for candyArray

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 120, green: 113, blue: 165, alpha: 100)


    self.person = [

        Candy(category:"За перфектна чревна флора", name:"Пробиен", imageName: "Probien1.png", testlabel: "проиен", latinNames: "probien"),

        Candy(category:"Подкрепа на вените", name:"Рувенор", imageName:"Ruvenor1.png", testlabel: "рувенор", latinNames: "ruvenor"),

        Candy(category:"Грижа за диабетиците",name: "Диабекан", imageName: "Diabekan1.png", testlabel: "диабекан", latinNames: "diabekan"),

        Candy(category:"Максимална грижа за простатата", name: "Простамакс", imageName: "Prostamaks1.png", testlabel: "простамакс", latinNames: "prostamaks"),

        Candy(category:"Женско здраве", name: "Агнес", imageName: "Agnes1.png", testlabel: "агнес", latinNames: "agnes"),

        Candy(category:"Капанът за мазнини", name: "Хитозан", imageName: "Hitozan1.png", testlabel: "хитозан", latinNames: "hitozan"),

        Candy(category:"Продукти с екстракт от гинко билоба", name: "Гинко синергия", imageName: "GinkoSinergiq1.png", testlabel: "гинко синергия", latinNames: "ginko sinergiq"),

        Candy(category:"За контрол на холестерола",name: "Нолипид", imageName: "Nolipid1.png", testlabel: "нолипид", latinNames: "nolipid"),

        Candy(category:"За нормална перисталтика", name: "Диарид про", imageName: "DiaridPro1.png", testlabel: "диарид про", latinNames: "diarid pro"),
        Candy(category:"За пациенти с ракови заболявания", name: "Авемар", imageName: "Avemar1.png", testlabel: "авемар", latinNames: "avemar"),
        Candy(category:"За здраво гърло и силен имунитет", name: "Фитолор", imageName: "Fitolor1.png", testlabel: "фитолор", latinNames: "fitolor")


    ]



    myTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 213
    searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()


    myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 120, green: 113, blue: 165, alpha: 1)

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {


                    return self.filteredCandies.count
    } else {
        return self.person.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell

    var candy : Candy

    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Candy object from the appropriate array

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {


        candy = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]

    } else {
        candy = person[indexPath.row]

    }

    cell.label1.text = candy.name
    cell.label2.text = candy.category


    //cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

   // let item = candies[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(candy.name, label2Text: candy.category, image1: candy.imageName, testlabel: candy.testlabel, latinNames: candy.latinNames)

    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var candy : Candy

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView)
    {

        candy = self.filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
        if (indexPath.row == 0){

            // Present Your first view controller

            let detailedViewController: ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
            // Present Second view controller

            let detailedViewController1: PageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductsPageViewController") as! PageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 2){

            let detailedViewController2: DiabekanThirdCellPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiabekanPageViewController") as! DiabekanThirdCellPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController2, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 3){

            let detailedViewController3: ProstamaksPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProstamaksPageViewController") as! ProstamaksPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController3, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 4){
            let detailedViewController4: AgnesPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AgnesPageViewController") as! AgnesPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController4, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 5){
            let detailedViewController5: HitozanPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HitozanPageViewController") as! HitozanPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController5, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 6){

            let detailedViewController6: GinkoSinergiqPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GinkoSinergiqPageViewController") as! GinkoSinergiqPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController6, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } else if (indexPath.row == 7){

            let detailedViewController7: NolipidPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NolipidPageViewController") as! NolipidPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController7, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 8){

            let detailedViewController8: DiaridPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiaridPageViewController") as! DiaridPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController8, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 9){

            let detailedViewController9: AvemarPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AvemarPageViewController") as! AvemarPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController9, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 10){

            let detailedViewController10: FitolorPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FitolorPageViewController") as! FitolorPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController10, animated: true, completion: nil)



        }else if (indexPath.row == 11){

        }
    }
    else
    {
        candy = self.person[indexPath.row]

        if (indexPath.row == 0){

            // Present Your first view controller

            let detailedViewController: ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
            // Present Second view controller

            let detailedViewController1: PageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductsPageViewController") as! PageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 2){

            let detailedViewController2: DiabekanThirdCellPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiabekanPageViewController") as! DiabekanThirdCellPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController2, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 3){

            let detailedViewController3: ProstamaksPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProstamaksPageViewController") as! ProstamaksPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController3, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 4){
            let detailedViewController4: AgnesPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AgnesPageViewController") as! AgnesPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController4, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 5){
            let detailedViewController5: HitozanPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HitozanPageViewController") as! HitozanPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController5, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (indexPath.row == 6){

            let detailedViewController6: GinkoSinergiqPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GinkoSinergiqPageViewController") as! GinkoSinergiqPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController6, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } else if (indexPath.row == 7){

            let detailedViewController7: NolipidPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NolipidPageViewController") as! NolipidPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController7, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 8){

            let detailedViewController8: DiaridPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiaridPageViewController") as! DiaridPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController8, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 9){

            let detailedViewController9: AvemarPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AvemarPageViewController") as! AvemarPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController9, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if (indexPath.row == 10){

            let detailedViewController10: FitolorPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FitolorPageViewController") as! FitolorPageViewController

            self.presentViewController(detailedViewController10, animated: true, completion: nil)



        }else if (indexPath.row == 11){

        }

    }

}

   /* let infoViewController: InfoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InfoViewController") as! InfoViewController

    infoViewController.label01 = candy.name
    infoViewController.label02 = candy.category
    infoViewController.imageFile = candy.imageName

     self.presentViewController(infoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} */

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    // Filter the array using the filter method

    self.filteredCandies = self.person.filter({( candy: Candy ) -> Bool in

        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (candy.category == scope)
        let categoryMatch1 = (scope == "All") || (candy.name == scope)
        let categoryMatch2 = (scope == "All") || (candy.name == scope)
        let categoryMatch3 = (scope == "All") || (candy.name == scope)
        let categoryMatch4 = (scope == "All") || (candy.name == scope)


        let stringMatch = candy.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
        let stringMatch1 = candy.category.rangeOfString(searchText)
        let stringMatch2 = candy.testlabel.rangeOfString(searchText)
        let stringMatch3 = candy.imageName.rangeOfString(searchText)
        let stringMatch4 = candy.latinNames.rangeOfString(searchText)

        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil) || categoryMatch1 && (stringMatch1 != nil) || categoryMatch2 && (stringMatch2 != nil) || categoryMatch3 && (stringMatch3 != nil) || categoryMatch4 && (stringMatch4 != nil)


    })



}


func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)


            return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text)
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: If you click the top cell, it will always point to indexPath.row == 0. Unrelated to the problem, as a general rule, when you are using else if's like that, use a switch statement.

Comment: Also, what is the variable "candy" used for? Right now it isn't used anywhere. What you are filtering and what you are picking based on the filter is unclear and makes it difficult to solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the info with the whole tableview controller. Could you please help me to set up the switch that I need. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Just convert indexPath.row to int so the comparision won't fail. IndexPath.row is an NSInteger so do the conversion first to an int variable then do the comparision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt at solving the problem with the information given:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var candy : Candy

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        candy = self.filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        candy = self.person[indexPath.row]
    }

    var detailedViewController: UIViewController!

    switch candy.name {
    case "Пробиен" :

        // Present Your first view controller
        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

        break
    case "Рувенор" :

        // Present Second view controller
        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductsPageViewController") as! PageViewController

        break
    case "Диабекан" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiabekanPageViewController") as! DiabekanThirdCellPageViewController

        break
    case "Простамакс" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProstamaksPageViewController") as! ProstamaksPageViewController

        break
    case "Агнес" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AgnesPageViewController") as! AgnesPageViewController

        break
    case "Хитозан" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HitozanPageViewController") as! HitozanPageViewController

        break

    case  "Гинко синергия" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GinkoSinergiqPageViewController") as! GinkoSinergiqPageViewController

        break
    case "Нолипид" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NolipidPageViewController") as! NolipidPageViewController

        break
    case "Диарид про" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiaridPageViewController") as! DiaridPageViewController

        break
    case "Авемар" :

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AvemarPageViewController") as! AvemarPageViewController

        break
    case "Фитолор":

        detailedViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FitolorPageViewController") as! FitolorPageViewController

        break
    default:
        break
    }

    if detailedViewController != nil {
        self.presentViewController(detailedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

This is a replacement for your didSelectRowAtIndex function. This filters based on the Candy.name property. If this is not what you're looking for, then please let me know what is wrong with it and I will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much this was exactly what I needed.